# Python coding for RPSLS

Tags: python

Total programming newbie trying to learn python. I did a RPSLS code for an online free class and can't understand why the computer says "PLAYER WINS" no matter what. The computer is changing but player is not...and even if there is a tie the player "wins."

Could someone point me in the right direction - here is the code link? I have tried everything and nothing works. THANKS IN ADVANCE! This is driving me crazy.

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user2-WEFezkBMoi-3.py

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't read like English:

```
if mod == 3 or 4:
```

This is interpreted as:

```
if (mod == 3) or (4):
```

Since you have `or 4` in that `if` condition, even if `mod` is not `3`, `or 4` will make the condition always be `True` because `4` is truthy.

To solve this, just use lists or tuples and check to see if `mod` is a member of that object:

```
if mod in [3, 4]:
if mod in (3, 4):
```